# On geodesics in Schwarzschild spacetime

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity, semi-riemannian-geometry

I am required to show that a circular lightlike geodesic exists in the Schwarzschild spacetime, and to find its radius. What's the best way to start this?

Comment: Hint: that geodesic can't be outside the event horizon (where geodesics escape to infinity); this leaves a natural spot to start looking. The phrase "Trapped surface" may help.

Comment: It also can't be inside the event horizon, since things inside black holes are famously doomed to end up at the singularity. So there's really only one place it can be.

Answer (score -2):

You can start with the system of geodesic equations together with the Schwarzschild metric expression divided by $d\tau^2$ (formulated in terms of $u^\mu := dx^\mu /d\tau$). Coordinates $x^\mu := (x^0 := ct, r, \theta, \varphi)$. Then you can obtain geodesics by assuming as $u^2 \equiv 0$ ($\theta = \pi/2$) due to the spherical symmetry. Solutions in $u^0$ and $u^3$ are evident thanks to this symmetry.

Comment: Would be nice if you format your answer

Comment: [Please, format your answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)